# How to resolve Unexpected response code 400 While POST data using API with Volley Library

Tags: javascript, java, android, api, android-volley

As I am unable to post data using this API. I am getting the response code of 400 so can u help me to get out of this.

**This is My Activity**

```
String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users";
try {
                    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
                    body.put("email", email);
                    body.put("password", password);
                    body.put("role", role);

                    final String requestBody = body.toString();

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Log.d("SignupActivity", "onResponse" + String.valueOf(response));
                                }
                            }
                            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error.......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }){

                        @Override
                        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

                            try {
                                return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    MySingleTon.getInstance(SignupActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

**And here is My SingleTon class**

```
public class MySingleTon {
private static MySingleTon mInstance;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleTon(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized MySingleTon getInstance(Context context){
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new MySingleTon(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return  requestQueue;
}

public void addToRequestQueue(Request request){
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

**Here is the details of error**

> 12-12 17:00:56.206 13835-14349/oakridgebs.com.flexijob I/System.out: [socket][/10.162.143.245:37838] connected
>       [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
>       12-12 17:00:56.207 13835-14349/oakridgebs.com.flexijob I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
>       12-12 17:00:57.096 13835-14349/oakridgebs.com.flexijob E/Volley: [2174] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users
>       12-12 17:00:57.123 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob W/System.err: com.android.volley.ClientError
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199)
>       12-12 17:00:57.123 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
>       12-12 17:00:57.134 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{a22a09 Toast,ident = 2}
>       12-12 17:00:57.177 13835-13876/oakridgebs.com.flexijob D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>       12-12 17:01:12.371 13835-13876/oakridgebs.com.flexijob W/MALI: glDrawArrays:770: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 6950
>       12-12 17:01:54.101 13835-13876/oakridgebs.com.flexijob W/MALI: glDrawArrays:770: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8209
>       12-12 17:01:59.890 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob I/InputMethodManager: [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=oakridgebs.com.flexijob, inputType=0x81, imeOptions=0x4001006, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{290b673e VFED..CL .F...... 40,344-660,432 #7f0800c1 app:id/signup_confirm_password}, mServedInputConnectionWrapper=android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper@36ef7c3c
>       12-12 17:01:59.915 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{5272e92 token=android.os.BinderProxy@38cb8063 {oakridgebs.com.flexijob/oakridgebs.com.flexijob.SignupActivity}}
>       12-12 17:01:59.934 13835-13835/oakridgebs.com.flexijob D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@38cb8063

I am unable to post data as it is showing response 400 when I run the code. 
Can you please solve it?

[image: Here is my Postman]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400 [check this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739703/android-retrofit-cant-convert-the-returned-json-reponse-to-the-specified-model?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the anatomy of an HTTP request? A 400 error is usually returned from an incomplete request. I usually run into errors making requests with curl or Telnet when I'm missing the Host field. Make sure that after your start line, there is something along the lines of *Host: example.com*. This is a requirement of HTTP 1.1.

If you keep running into errors, I would do a Wireshark packet capture and see what the HTTP packets look like. This could help you determine if there's a missing Host field in the request.